# Ubuntu 16.04 Can't connect with FTP, only SFTP

Tags: 16.04, ftp, sftp

I'm currently running an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS, to host my website and files. My default (S)FTP port is 22, but when I use SFTP, it takes literal hours to upload files.

- I have a 30mb/s upload speed.
- With uploading, uploads can go as slow as 5kb/s.

Now are my files not very special, so I'm not in the need of an encrypted connection (just trust me here). And I know for a fact, that my uploads with FTP can cap out at the max. 30mbs/sec.

But when I tried to open FTP port 21 on my server (no errors thrown) for both tcp / udp, my FTP Client (WinSCP) refuses to connect. Does anybody know what can cause this? or a simple fix for the slow sftp connection?

I'm pretty new at this, so thanks for the help!

Comment: if you have been able to upload at over 30mbs/sec, with FTP... how is FTP not working?

Comment: By `mb/s` do you mean `megabits per second` or `megabytes per second`?  Usually 'upload speeds' are in megabits.

Comment: @Thomas Ward in megabytes in this case. but that doesn't matter for the question, because sftp is stil underperforming. and i cant get to ftp

Comment: Did you install a FTP server?

Comment: @thim24 you need to install an FTP server for FTP to work - it doesn't come available 'out of the box'.  As for 'slow connection', where's the server related to you?  If it's a good distance away then your speed *will* be impacted, even if it's FTP.  Also, FTP is **insecure** so you really should avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

ftp uses more than one port - control and data port...
Control port - 21
Data port - 20

Open port 20, as you have done 21.

Comment: stil didnt fix it sadly. connecting with either port 20 or 21 threw the same connection refused error

Comment: what did you do to open the port? Can you post the output of `ss -tuln`... and it may just be semantics here, but it's not "either" port, FTP uses both ports.

Comment: connection refused means there's no FTP server listening on those ports.  Did you install an FTP server software?